# If the discriminant of a quadratic form is a perfect square then one can factor this quadratic form

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ be a quadratic form with integer coefficients. Let $b^2-4ac$ be its discriminant. If the discriminant is a perfect square then the quadratic form can be written as two linear forms.

I tried to complete the square (by multiplying with $4a$) to have the discriminant involved, but that didn't help :/.

Comment: A quadratic form is a homogeneous polynomial. So I suppose the it is $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$. Or not?

Comment: Corrected it, thanks :)

Comment: How do you take a quadratic form and "write it as two linear forms"?  You mean a product of homogeneous polynomials degree $1$?

Comment: I want to show that if the discriminant of $f(x,y)$ is a perfect square i can write it as $f(x,y)=(\alpha_1x+\beta_1y)(\alpha_2x+\beta_2y).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my thought on this: Completing the square:

$$z=ax^2+bxy+cy^2=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}xy+\frac{c}{a}y^2\right)$$

Ignore the $a$ upfront for a moment. Continue:

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}y\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}y^2+\frac{c}{a}y^2=\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}y\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}y^2$$

This can be factored as the difference of two squares IF $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square. Can you finish from here?

Comment: I think it is ok now?

Comment: Looks good to me now!

Comment: Some spaces and double dollar signs will make this, I believe, look much better. +1 BTW, the "completing the square" part is only after the first calculations, which simply are factoring out $\;a\;$ .

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Actually I find myself still a novice in this mathjax stuff. Truth is, many times I do copy-paste from another post to write my answers in proper format because I can't find the right keys...That is in particular with those integrals, limits, matrices etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is still something not clear for me. If I continue this I must somehow argue that $(b-\delta)$ and $(b+\delta)$ are divisible by two ($\delta$ is the root of the discriminant).

Comment: @DonAntonio I want to write $f(x,y)=(\alpha_1x+\beta_1y)(\alpha_2x+\beta_2y)$ where $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ are integers. So far I have that $\alpha_{1,2}=a$, $\beta_1=\frac{b-\delta}{2}$ and $\beta_2=\frac{b+\delta}{2}.$

Comment: @Marc We began with the assumption $$b^2-4ac=d^2\implies (b-d)(b+d)=4ac$$and since $\;b-d\,,\,\,b+d\;$ have the same parity and the right hand above is even you're done

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks :)